# Relative error when chopping is used of a 32 bit floating point number in IEEE 754 format

Tags: numerical-methods, notation, numerical-linear-algebra, floating-point

Find the binary representation of 85.125 using IEEE 754 standard 32-bit floating point
number presentation. Find the relative error if chopping is used.

I calculated the binary representation of 85.125 using IEEE 754 standard 32-bit, which is:

```
0 10000101 01010100100000000000000
```

Now how to calculate the relative error if chopping is used?

Comment: Your question is not very clear - chopping to how many digits? Do you want to chop the decimal representation or the binary representation?

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik This is a textbook exercise problem. It asked to chop the binary representation. But it didn't mention the number of digits.

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik: it is actually an well posed problem if you know a little about converting decimal to binary numbers in a computer.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Maybe I am mistaken and it is indeed well-posed. But from what I recall of electronics/ binary representation, both chopping and rounding problems specify the number of digits to round to. Otherwise, we will get different values of error for rounding to different digits, even though the calculation itself will be trivial.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for the response! I couldn't figure out the problem from R implementation.

Comment: @DevashsihKaushik: If you understand that much and you think the problem is simple, share a solution with the OP instead of qualifying in as a "blatant" PSQ. Be helpful!

Comment: @Taylor: you may try a search under different computer language (C, Fortran, Python, etc) Maybe you can implement the algorithm yourself, or post the problem in a computer related site with SE.

Comment: @Taylor: How do you read (in human form) the string "0 10000101 01010100100000000000000" The part "10000101" does not match 85 in binary representation. I have not checked the mantissa part "01010100100000000000000", but it maybe that I am not interpreting the 0-1 sequence correctly.

Comment: @Taylor: I got $85.125=(1010101.001)_2$.